# Checking whether a variable is null or NOT

Tags: javascript

```
var DEST_VALUE = 1
var APPDAYS_AFTER = 2

}
```

How can i check whether the variable holds some value or not. When i do this, it does not work...

Comment: This will work as expected - neither `if` condition will evaluate to `true` so the inner code will never be hit. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `if(!DEST_VALUE)` is same as `if(DEST_VALUE == null)`, and from the code this will always be `false`. So it will not produce any result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I test whether a variable has a value in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610842/how-can-i-test-whether-a-variable-has-a-value-in-javascript)

Comment: @Talha Not strictly true - if `DEST_VALUE` was 0 it would also evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @Talha: *"`if(!DEST_VALUE)` is same as `if(DEST_VALUE == null)`"* No, it doesn't. For instance, `!0` is true but `0 == null` is false. More to the point, though, `if (!DEST_VALUE)` has *nothing* to do with `null` unless `DEST_VALUE` happens to be `null` (in which case, the expression is true). It's about coercing the given value to a boolean, not comparing it to `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it doesn't do anything, because in your example `DEST_VALUE` resolves to true like `APPDAYS_AFTER`. Value that resolve to false when converted to a boolean in javascript are:

```
false
null
undefined
The empty string ''
The number 0
The number NaN (yep, 'Not a Number' is a number, it is a special number)
```

if you write

```
if(!DEST_VALUE){
    txtSiteId.value = fileContents.Settings.SiteID;
}
```

you write "if `DEST_VALUE` is not true do something" (in your case it does nothing). If you want to check if a variables hold a value:

```
if(DEST_VALUE !== undefined){
     //do something
}
```

Comment: This will throw an ReferenceError as you may not reference variables that are not declared in JS. See my answer for a solution.

Comment: @Steffen: The question clearly shows the variables being declared.

Comment: But what about FileNotFound??? http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use such function to check if variable is empty or not:

```
function empty( mixed_var ) {
    return ( typeof(mixed_var) === 'undefined' || mixed_var === "" || mixed_var === 0   || mixed_var === "0" || mixed_var === null  || mixed_var === false );
}
```

Comment: Why would you do all this? `!myVar` checks for 'falsy' values, not just explicit `false` (such as `myVar === false`), so you don't need a bloated function to do the same as the native language capabilities.

Comment: By the way, a string representation of `"0"` shouldn't evaluate to `false`, only an empty string...

Comment: @Chris: Well, it's his function, he can do that if it matches his definition of "empty". It doesn't match *mine*, but... :-)

Comment: Yes - that function was changed several times and you can see the final result. Why !myVar is not used - because all is not so simple. I had some issues when it worked not as I expected too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "holds some value" like in "the variable has been created so it exists", right? Otherwise, your approach works perfectly fine.

If you want to check whether a variable exists in javascript, you have to check its parent object for the property - otherwise the script will fail. Each object in javascript belongs to a parent object, even if it seems to be global (then, it belongs to the window object). So, try something like:

```
  if (window.DEST_VALUE) 
    // do something
```