# How to find whether the particular array variable is empty or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array variable like `Array[0]`, and now I need to check whether that `Array[0]` contains value or not inside of it. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/610842/544184

Comment: And what's your definition of whether or not the variable "contains value"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array and call it eg. `list`, then you can check if it has some elements in the following manner:

```
if (list.length){
    // has some elements (exactly list.length elements)
} else {
    // does not have any elements
}
```

See the following for details: [Documentation on `length` property of `Array` objects in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Answer (score 1):

Checks if that array exists and does something if not so.

```
if(!array[0])
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: However you need it, but thanks for the correction :) I'm always open to good tips.

Comment: @Karlisson: You say `false`, `0` etc. are not "_values_"? OP asked: "_I need to check whether that Array[0] contains value or not inside of it_".

Comment: @Karlisson: The original was "_need to check weather that array[0] containing value or not inside of if..._", so I would not expect it to stay unedited ;) But it is matter of interpretation in that case, I suppose ;)

Comment: The code would generally work but if(foo[0] !== undefined){} is more accurate, as your code would fail if it had a false value.

Comment: Do all browser interprete 'undefined' the same? I mean is it legit?

Comment: @manticore: It depends. `undefined` sometimes can be overwritten with something else (although can be restored by simple trick). You can also use `typeof foo[0] !== 'undefined'`, I believe. Please search on StackOverflow for other tipses on how to deal with `undefined` being actually defined (such as when you invoke `(function(undefined){/* your code here */}());`, the `undefined` variable within the anonymous function is actually undefined, as you do not pass it within call / brackets calling the function).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(array[0] !== undefined){
 // array[0] is defined.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//pass array variable to this function

function isEmpty(array){
   if(array.length == 0)
    return true;
   else
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Why would you want the added complexity and overhead using a function for this?

Comment: if anyone dont want to use functions he can just check "array.length == 0" but if number of times wants to check it is empty or not that time, instead of repeating code i think function is good option...

Comment: Question asks to check if first index is empty, not if the array is empty.